# Can I use fetch to call the Notion API?

Tags: notion-api

I want to use Notion as a content gateway for a SPA. Can I use the Notion API from fetch? I'm trying to use fetch to get the data but It's not working because of CORS.

```js
let notion = fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_NOTION_API_URL+'/databases/'+import.meta.env.VITE_NOTION_APP_DATABASE+'/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'omit',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${import.meta.env.VITE_NOTION_API_SECRET}`,
        "Notion-Version": `${import.meta.env.VITE_NOTION_API_VERSION}`,
      }
    })
```

It's this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The Notion API does not support CORS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @adlopez15.

Comment: It's crazy how long it took me to discover this critical piece of information. Is this stated somewhere or do you just happen to know it for a fact @adlopez15?

Comment: `We currently don't support CORS and don't recommend making API calls from a web page.` https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-js/issues/96

Comment: Technically it is possible to use a server side `fetch` implementation like `undici` or `node-fetch`.