# Notion API, Vanilla JS, Fetch does not work

Tags: javascript, fetch, notion-api

I don't understand why a simple fetch request is unsuccessful via Vanilla JS but successful via Postman:

[image: Insomia]

```
const getNotion = () => {
  fetch(
    "https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/[DBID_HERE]",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer [SECRET_HERE]",
        "Notion-Version": "2021-05-11"
      }
    }
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log("Request Failed", err));
};

getNotion();
```

The response is **Request Failed  TypeError: Failed to fetch**.
Both DBID and SECRET are correct.

Comment: Please show the respective postman request

Comment: Did you check the CORS issue?

Comment: The CORS issue? What do you mean by this?

Comment: Added Insomnia screenshot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68015381/can-i-use-fetch-to-call-the-notion-api

Comment: What does the browser’s network tab say about the actual request…?

Comment: https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-js/issues/96

Comment: Yup that's the issue. I can't believe they rolled out an API without client support. Thanks

Comment: well, if you think about it, it isn't that strange, that they don't support requests from webpages. Because to make requests from a webpage you would need to expose your credentials to everyone using that webpage. So it seems quite logical to execute requests to the database from your server, which is a protected environment.

Answer (score 1):

Notion API doesn't support CORS (if you want you could learn more about it). And also in case you want your site to go online you really should not call APIs from your website because it will public your credentials. So the easiest solution for me who doesn't want to spend much time on BE is to use serverless functions.